# How to remove unnecessary files from a zip package in Chocolatey? Commands?

Tags: installation, nuget-package, chocolatey

Does Chocolatey provide some commands to filter or remove files after unzipping / installing them? I couldn't find anything API related in this direction.

Today I created my first working chocolatey package "pedeps". chocolateyinstall.ps1:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';
$toolsDir   = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
$url32      = 'https://github.com/brechtsanders/pedeps/releases/download/0.1.5/pedeps-0.1.5-win32.zip'
$url64      = 'https://github.com/brechtsanders/pedeps/releases/download/0.1.5/pedeps-0.1.5-win64.zip'
$checksum32  = 'f61b708a27e834dc70009854a56430a7e49062f67e91d5f8bb3fe880b243e2ad'
$checksum64  = '71ac500464ef6a06763ee5cda74c2b39504d4933267a34b8318be723a2e0f6fd'



$packageArgs = @{
  packageName   = 'pedeps'
  unzipLocation = $toolsDir
  url           = $url32
  url64bit      = $url64

  softwareName  = 'pedeps'
  checksum      = $checksum32
  checksumType  = 'sha256'
  checksum64    = $checksum64
  checksumType64= 'sha256'
}

Install-ChocolateyZipPackage @packageArgs
```

The zip contains **/bin, /include and /lib folder**. **Only the bin folder is relevant.**  I would like to keep only /bin and delete everything else. The other files are unnecessary and I like to keep the installation clean and small.

*I know in this case it's only a couple kilobytes in saved space, but I plan to add some more packages in the future which might be bigger.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-zip-package#specificfolder-string

There is a SpecificFolder property which you can set on the `Install-ChocolateyZipPackage` cmdlet.

This will extract only the specific folder from the zip file that you are interested in.

Comment: And is there something also for specific files?

Comment: Not for files, no.  These would need to be deleted manually after extracting the zip file.